# Enter size of an array in a struct

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have an array in a struct and i want to enter the size of it via the user's input.

```
struct queue
{
    int maxSize;
    int count;
    int* element;
};
```

element is the array, and now i want to set the size of it to '5' and to initialize all of the '5' cells to '0'

```
    struct queue q;

    *element -> ??
```

Comment: Choose a language, either `C` or `C++`.  They are not the same thing, and the answer can differ if it's C++.

Answer (score 2):

You tagged your question as `C++`, so here is a `C++` solution.  Forget about pointers and just use `std::vector<int>`.

```
#include <vector>
struct queue
{
    int maxSize;
    int count;
    std::vector<int> element;
    queue(int n=5) : element(n) {}
};
```

Then

```
queue q;
```

will construct a `queue` object with 5 elements in the `element` member.  No need for `malloc`, `calloc` or `free`.

Note:

If you change your tags to `C` instead of both `C` and `C++`, you see why it's important that you use the correct tags.  You can't do the above in `C`, and it effectively is the same thing as using the pointer and using `malloc` as the other answers have given.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `element` is not an *array*; it's a *pointer* (to an `int`).

If you want to allocate memory for it and zero initialize it then you can use `calloc()` as follows:

```
struct queue q;

q.element = calloc(5, sizeof(int)); // Allocate memory for 5 int's.
```

And you'll be able to use it like, for example:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   q.element[i] = i+1;
```

After use, remember to free() it:

```
free(q.element);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that `element`  size will be chosen by user input, you must allocate the array dynamically.

```
q.element = (int*) malloc(5*sizeof(int));
memset(q.element, 0, 5*sizeof(int)); // will initialize array values to 0.
```

Comment: Do **not** cast the result of `malloc`!! Also don't use `malloc` in C++

Answer (score -1):

In your case you need run time memory allocation feature so You can use `malloc` or `calloc` function for run time memory allocation in C. and for C++ you can use `new` .

### For C language

```
struct queue q;
q.element = (int *)calloc(5,sizeof(int));
```

here Calloc returns a pointer to the allocated memory. The memory is set to zero.

### For C++ language

```
struct queue q;
q.element = new int[5]();
```

Here () is used to value-initialize the elements and it set value to 0.

Comment: Thanks!
How do i use Here()?

Comment: @JamesClark "Here()" is not a function. The post is saying that the parentheses are used to initialize to zero.

Comment: just as I use in my statement. It only initialize array element values to 0 .